# Which physical phenomena are not objects?

Tags: terminology, physics, definitions

I come from the world of OOP programming and I find OOP terms convenient to describe everything that has properties or fields and possibly some actions that may be applied to its properties/fields. Thus a class lists properties, fields and methods, while objects are concrete instances of this class.

It was [suggested by @goldilocks](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/18108/81) that:

> Not all physical phenomenon are "objects".

And:

> I think there is a lot of confusion about what "physical phenomenon"
>   refers to. It refers to things which can, or could (assuming perfect
>   knowledge) be explained in terms of physics.

What "things" can be explained in terms of physics and at the same time can't be described in terms of objects? Some examples?

Comment: In context, I meant things like fields, which could be represented in spirit if perhaps not (ala quentin's answer) in perfect realistic detail by an OOP object (I'm sure they often usefully are).  But WRT colloquial/conventional language about the physical world (we are not all programmers), I'd say a field is a *thing* which may be associated with objects but in and of itself is not an object.  No doubt there are other possible definitions though! Beyond that I don't have anything to add to that that the existing answers haven't covered.

Answer (score 3):

A field in continuus space-time. That would require an infinite memory.

Edit (precision following comments): that would require arrays with real-numbers as indexes, which cannot exist on a digital architecture.

Comment: This seems to need some qualification/elaboration -- not all field configurations require infinite memory for their description.

Comment: That's right but I was more thinking about how we would implement a generic field (not a particular configuration) in an object oriented programming language. Objects can have integer-indexed (countable) arrays but not (uncountable) real-indexed.

Comment: Having said that, even having a generic real-valued property is beyond the capabilities of a digital computer. Real numbers are always approximated.

Comment: @quen_tin I didn't ask about actual implementation of such objects. Let's say we have an infinite memory. Is there any problem after that?

Comment: I was worried you'd go there. If you assert that a single real number requires some sort "infinite amount of resources" then, pretty obviously, you can't represent anything with continuous degrees of freedom in a finite way.

Comment: @a1111exe it's not simply infinite memory: you need an uncountably infinite memory, and arrays with real numbers as indexes. They don't exist in actual languages (that doesn't make much sense on our finite architectures). Now you can "invent" them if you like, it depends how far from the actual you are willing to go...

Comment: @quen_tin It wasn't my intention to ask about a possibility of low-level implementation on computer systems. It's obvious that such implementation would be no more than a rough approximation like implementations of real numbers. I just wonder if there any problem with thinking about some 'physical phenomenon' in terms of classes and their instances - as a way of convenient but still descriptive and precise abstraction.

Comment: No I don't think there is any problem apart from representing infinities and continuum. It seems to me that you can represent anything discrete with OOP, or with relational databases for that matter (you might be interested in "applied ontologies" which is a field at the intersection of computer science and metaphysics). Now of course everything is a matter of interpretation (what you interpret classes and objects to physically represent).

Comment: Yeah, but int isn't big Z, and float isn't big R.  If you take this seriously then a building is not an object because its height is a real number, which demands more precision than any machine can have.  The classes float and double model 'the reals', so the real numbers are as much of an object as the building is.  From there a field is still an object because we can still compute (theoretically) its intensity at a point to the needed precision given all the other information predicting the effect (which must also be expressed or measurable-at-need, if we are doing physics.)

Comment: It depends on what you mean. The question is imprecise. But if the question is "can I implement a model of any physical theory in OOP" then the answer is clearly "no" for the reasons I gave. There is a sense in which models (in the logico-mathematical sense) are the objects of a theory, that which alledgedly corresponds to real physical phenomena (if the theory is true).

Comment: @quen_tin Note that one can construct OO computer models that use symbolic manipulation, and don't have the sorts of problems that I believe you are focused on.

Comment: @quen_tin Then a building is not an object in the sense of your objection.

Comment: @Dave that's a good point, although it would be a syntactic approach to theories (not models of reality but sentences about reality)

Comment: @jobemark I guess you can have a physical theory of buildings where they all have rational sizes... Just as you could have a simplified quantum field theory with finite ranges and values of course, that was your point I guess. If that's acceptable as a representation of physical phenomena then you're right.

Comment: @quen_tin Your answer would be right for a "field in continuous space-time." However, The universe is discrete, therefore any thing in it is an object which can be modeled in a computer to the precision allowed by the computer(s) being used.

Comment: @Guill that is certainly not true of Quantum Field Theory, which is our best contemporary physical theory. Nor is it true of standard (non-relativistic) Quantum Mechanics, where discrete phenomena take place in a continuous space-time. Quantum loop gravity attempts to discretize space-time but it is still speculative and not yet a full, established theory.

Answer (score 3):

Causal powers must be different *in kind* from the physical objects upon which they act. Consider, for example, *F = ma*. Rewind history to before we knew it had any problems. For all we knew back then, there was a real causal force which caused all objects to obey it, *precisely*. That is, there was something awfully like an abstract object, existing timelessly and without location in space, which *causes* all objects to act as if *F = ma*. Today, we know that *F = ma* is only an approximation. However, that's not really a problem, because we can just posit some more sophisticated version—perhaps some form of M-theory—which produces *F = ma* in some circumstances, a more complex General Relativity in other circumstances, and something even more complex near the event horizons of black holes.

One could try and deny the very idea of causation; [Regularity Theory](http://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/physical-law/regularity_theory.htm) is a view which does this. However, Regularity Theory has some serious problems, as pointed out by Rom Harré in [Causal Powers: Theory of Natural Necessity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/063116040X). One could also argue for a kind of causation which is located within spacetime instead of in the "timelessly and without location in space" manner which I discussed, above. However, this would require major changes in how we even think about science; it typically requires that how objects behave is *not* dependent on spacetime. Furthermore, it is hard not to think that some sort of *rationality* is required in how objects behave, such that if, say, the physical constants were different in one part of the universe than the other, that there would be an underlying law as to why and how they shift from being one value to another. It seems to keep coming back to laws which hold timelessly and without location in space, which means they are manifestly different from physical objects.

Comment: If the idea is to represent the content of a physical theory, the universality of laws of nature is not a real obstacle. Laws of nature can be conceived as relations between universals (e.g Armstrong). In OOP, the class / instance distinction is almost identical to the universal / particular distinction in metaphysics, and OOP languages  have built-in features for defining class-level operations, fields and constants  (e.g. in java through the "static" keyword).

Answer (score 3):

OOP objects are only 'objects in reality' by reference.  Right?  An actual employee at a a company is an object (but don't tell them that, they don't like it).  And that object 'is' (in an odd set-theoretical, naming-relation-upon-equivalence-class-via-relation way) the OOP 'object' that instantiates "class Employee: public Human" because we expect the operations on the latter to represent real facts about the former.

I am not sure it is a good definition, but if the criterion for being a physical phenomenon is the applicability of (some future) physics to them, then all physical phenomena are objects from the OOP point of view, in this same sort of referential way.  Physics is stated in laws that take mathematical forms.  Any foreseeable physics will still couch its entire range of predictions in the form of a theory with clauses that identify to what the equations apply and then some methods for prediction.  That seems to be the form theories take there, and anything that departs significantly from that form in the future, will probably not still be physics.

Such a law is an object, it produces the referents as sub-objects, works on them, and discards them.  So an atom is obviously not an OOP 'instance of a class', in reality, but a Bohr atom, or a deBroglie atom is one, because Bohr's and deBroglie's theories are objects and they attach to a certain part of our observational space and force us to re-encode whatever we see or imagine there into a specific finite representation.  This is just the same way we encode the employee as "new Employee(...)", only vague and computationally intractable.  Those objects will always have the form of an OOP object, just because that is what a theory has become for us -- a list of definitions, conditions and predictions.  Then the atom is the object those instances model in the same sense the real, physical employee a the object modeled by our cruder model of 'class Employee'.

[As noted elsewhere at great length I can't buy that definition, because I think we are no longer able to identify what we would and would not accept as a 'physical' theory, except to the degree it is just a form in which we want our science expressed.  You can make up math that predicts anything you can imagine, so it begs the question of what is physical just to say it could be described mathematically.  ('Reductivist monism' may be well defined but 'physical' is not, anymore.)]

If you are an hard-core idealist, it is a lot more obvious everything to which we can make a reference is an object.  Any clear idea of an entity or process is a model (consistent or otherwise) in some category of models, and OOP is just a framing of category theory.  But then, if you admit math as ideal, you have to deal with the intrinsic conflict between universality and negation (Russel's paradox).

Something cannot both be ideal and at the same time have to be coped to fit observed problems with its reality.  Formalistic solutions to math's boundary-issues discard universal universality -- only some things get to be universal, and the motivations as to which things those are are from practical observation, not principle.  To me these are not acceptable solutions from an idealistic point of view, because there is no good idealistic reason to seek them.  The few less formalistic, idealist solutions we have found, usually deeply impoverish math, and make it a lot harder to move forward.

Comment: Thanks! Could you be so kind and explain further your last sentence:

> But then, if you admit math as ideal, you have to deal with the intrinsic conflict between universality and negation.

Comment: Look up Russel's Paradox.  The problem here is some really basic problem we have when we use 'all' and 'not' together that lets us ask all those unanswerable questions of omnipotence and immovable objects.  So if idealism is true in some way, there is a human defect that prevents those grammatical concepts from getting along with mathematics.  Traditional mathematical logic gives up 'all', Intuitionistic mathematics gives up 'not', but both of those do not accord with natural human ideas.

Comment: Well, the same Russel provided us with his type theory - one way to discard these paradoxes. IMHO, the problem of all paradoxes about omnipotence lies in an undefined demand. Like demand to a straight square to be a perfect circle is just inconsistent and undefined. BTW, as far as I know, there is no authentic source that asserts that God is omnipotent. 'All-powerful' seems to be a less contradictory term.

Comment: Right, traditional mathematics discarded 'all' out of hand  (**like I just said**).  We took Wittgenstein's out -- "That whereof one cannot really speak must be consigned to silence."  But it is really hard to do math that way.  And we just pretend to.  No one asks, in group theory, well what if our underlying group is not a set?  It is a bizarre non-starter.

Comment: And whatever you think of God/esse/s, and what authoritatively can be said about one, it does not rule out the questions themselves, which every culture asks at some point.  It is still a real problem, even if you can make big excuses to ignore it.  Ignore < solve.  If natural human thought is to be trusted, not checked by physics, then its internal problems are important.

Comment: Do you really think that the 'natural human thought' is to be trusted? Do you really think that the human thought is to be checked only by physics?

Comment: No.  Did I say ONLY?  Do not put words in my mouth.

Comment: I've just asked. To understand. You know, natural languages are ambiguous. Don't be mad. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18708/discussion-between-jobermark-and-a1111exe).

Comment: I unwound the last sentence at greater length (so it is no longer the last sentence...)